# getting combined results from two get calls in java

Tags: java, mongodb, api, http, endpoint

Hi i would put the question in very simple terms.

I have two routes

1) localhost:8080/employee/employeeid which gives me employee details

2) localhost:8080/address/employeeid whcih gives me address details.

employeeid is common in both!
both these calles hit two different functions in getoneemployee() and getoneaddress().

i want a third endpoint localhost:8080/getdetails/employeeid which hits the above mentioned end points and produces an aggregate result.
i was able to make a end point which hit the database and got the aggreagate results, but i dont want to hit the db , i want to hit the endpoints made above.

is it possible to that? if yes then how should one go about it?
ps: i am using a mongo database. and sorry if it turns out to be a stupid question.